# How can I refresh the results of a MySQL query without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am wanting to refresh the results of a query I have periodically, say every 10-30 seconds. I am unsure how to implement code that I have read online into my own code as a lot of the time the scenario is different.

The MySQL query is on the same page as my jQuery and everything else.

Currently, I retrieve values of a MySQL table using this bit of PHP code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From auction WHERE category = 'Bathroom' ORDER BY ID DESC");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<form name='auction' id='auction" . $row['ID'] . "'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['ID'] . "' />
            <div class='auction-thumb'>
                <div class='auction-name'>" . $row['Item'] . "</div>";
            echo "<img class='auction' src='" . $row['ImagePath'] . "' />";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Current Bid: £<div class='nospace' id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['CurrentBid'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Name: <input type='text' class='bidder' name='bidname' autocomplete='off'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Bid: <input type='text' class='auction-text' name='bid' autocomplete='off'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Place Bid!' /></div>";
    echo "</div></form>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This retrieves multiple rows and they populate the page.

I would like to refresh or 'rerun' this query every so often, so that the Current Bid is updated.

I have this jQuery code already which posts the new bid to a PHP page, currently, anyone else looking at this page will not see the new bid until they refresh the page manually which is not great.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form[name="auction"]').submit(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('input[name="id"]').val();
            var bidname = $(this).find('input[name="bidname"]').val();
            var bid = $(this).find('input[name="bid"]').val();
            var currentbid = $('#'+id).text();
            var itemdesc = $(this).find('.auction-name').text();

            if (bidname == '')
            {
                alert("No name!")
                return false;   
            }

            if (bid > currentbid)
            {
                alert("Bid is greater than current bid");   
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Bid is too low!");
                return false;   
            }

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auction-handler.php",
            data: {bidname: bidname, bid: bid, id: id, itemdesc: itemdesc},
            success: function(data){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;

        }); 
    });
</script>
```

My auction-handler.php code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$con=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$bidname = $_POST['bidname'];
$bid = $_POST['bid'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$itemdesc = $_POST['itemdesc'];

$query = "UPDATE auction SET CurrentBid = '$bid', Bidder = '$bidname' WHERE ID = '$id'";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO auction_log (Item, Bid, Bidder) VALUES ('$itemdesc','$bid','$bidname')";



mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

A lot of things I have read online do not really help me and I am too much of a begginer to be able to write it myself properly. Somethings I am really struggling to understand how to do, and how I can implement it in my scenario.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you use `setTimeout` to "schedule" your ajax call. but calling `window.location.reload()` is going to force a full page reload anyways, so you have to use the ajax results to change PART of your page, not rebuild the whole thing.

Comment: Your basic polling option is to use `setInterval` with an ajax request to get the current bid

Comment: Ok, but I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: You can start with scheduling a reload of the page like you do now after posting. Then you can move to something using ajax when you get that working. It's about 3 lines of javascript so you should give it a try.

Comment: Thanks - but that shows me how I can use ajax to submit a form. Something I already have working in my code. I am unsure on what to have on the PHP page and how to target the current bid div with the new value

Comment: @jeroen Yes that would work but my concern with that is if someone was placing a bid during the page refresh, they would lose whatever they were typing.

Comment: Good thinking, so you'd have to reset the timeout on the `keyUp` event for example. Or you go for ajax straight away, no more page refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not far off.

What you need to do is replace the html of the relevant table with the response of the ajax request rather than reloading the entire page.

So instead of:

```
success: function(data){
            window.location.reload();
        }
```

You can do:

```
success: function(data){
            $('#auction'+id).before(data).remove();
        }
```

**Edit**

Periodic ajax request:

php:

```
//update-handler.php
$response = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From auction WHERE category = 'Bathroom' ORDER BY ID DESC");


 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $response[] = (object)array('id'=>$row['ID'],'val'=>$row['CurrentBid']);
 // get all the updated rows and put them into response array;
 }

header('content-type=application/json');
exit(json_encode($response)); // send the json serialized response to jquery ajax
```

javascript:

```
var timeout = 30000 //30 seconds
setInterval(function () {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update-handler.php",
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (i, d) {  //loop though each bid amount from ajax response
            $('#auction' + d.id).find('.nospace').html(d.val); //nospace is not a good target name, but its the only unique selector for that div

        });
    }
    });
}, timeout);
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but then whatever was bidded on disappears from my query until I refresh the page.

Comment: so what is in `auction-handler.php` is that the code posted in the top part of your question?

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't sure whether or not to add this code is it's not as relevant for what I'm trying to do, I will edit the question with the code on this page. However this just puts the bid into MySQL.

Comment: ok, so ive looked at the edit, the update script doesn't seem to return anything, it just updates the table. so why not have it also run a select query after the insert and retrieve the newly added row, + any rows added by other bidders. Sorry, i assumed you were already doing this hence my above answer

Comment: No problem. My issue then is that the page wouldn't update for everyone else. Sorry, I'm finding it very difficult to do what I am wanting to do.

Comment: oh. ok yes so in that case you would need a javascript timer to be running and periodically making ajax requests, what you probably don't want to do is re-draw the bid amount input on each request otherwise it might get cleared as the user is typing if a request occurs at that time, so you probably want the php to just return the current bid amount, ill edit my answer to give you some ideas

Comment: Ok cool, I'll keep a watch for the edit. Thanks for taking the time to help me. I imagine I would need to return the current bid, and the ID as how would the returned data know in which "Current Bid" div it would belong? Thanks again

Comment: hey, ive added some more code, please be aware, i havn't tested it, its more to give you an idea of the approach you can take

Comment: I fixed some syntax errors in the js, sorry I guess i shouldn't try to writ code  direct in the editor :/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I'll give this a try today, it doesn't have to be perfect I just needed something I can go off, and then change as I need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey mate, just wanted to say it works perfect. It didn't at first but this is because the dataType: "json" was missing from the ajax, but adding this in fixes the problem.

Comment: ahh, whoops. i made a mistake in the php, `header('content-type=application/json');` should have been `header('content-type:application/json');` then it'd have worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="results">
 ...
</div>

<script>
var time = 30000;
function autoRefresh()
{
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "HMTL",
  url: "auction-handler.php",
  data: {bidname: bidname, bid: bid, id: id, itemdesc: itemdesc},
  success: function(data){
   $("#results").append(data);
  }
 });
}

setTimeout("autoRefresh()", time);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this looks close - but my problem (and the main one I have come across with reading online) is that I will be updating potentially more than one bid at a time. My query pulls through a lot of rows, all with their own ID, so how could I do $("#results").append(data); if the div I am putting it in has an id that is different for each record?

Comment: You can use a class $('.results')... or other name that you want.

Comment: Using that your response ajax, you can put all results in a fixed div like a id='results' or a class='results'. But, do you want single results every time?